# using the ruby gem and just sinatra and ruby (not rails), how can I connect to a bonsai elasticsearch instance?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, sinatra

I am trying to get up and running with bonsai. I intend to use sinatra and ruby (not rails) although right now I am just trying to connect from my local machine. The script is:

```
require "csv"
require "elasticsearch"
require 'elasticsearch/transport'
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://uz09z96il1:5g9p3h8jow@hectors-first-starte-5298580603.us-west-2.bonsai.io', log: true
#Elasticsearch::Client.new host: 'https://uz09z96il1:5g9p3h8jow@hectors-first-starte-5298580603.us-west-2.bonsai.io', log: true
#Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new('https://uz09z96il1:5g9p3h8jow@hectors-first-starte-5298580603.us-west-2.bonsai.io')
#client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
#Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: 'https://uz09z96il1:5g9p3h8jow@hectors-first-starte-5298580603.us-west-2.bonsai.io', log: true
CSV.open("candidates.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |item, i|
    next if i == 0
    p item
    client.index  index: 'data', type: 'person', body: '{
        "first": "#{item[1]}",
        "last": "#{item[2]}"
        }'
end
end
```

The basic error is that connection is refused, in this particular example like so:

```
uninitialized constant Elasticsearch::Model (NameError)
```

As you can see, from the commented out lines, I have tried as many variations as I can think of.

What's the best way to accomplish this? All help gratefully received, thank you.

Comment: what ruby gems are using (trying to use) for this?

Comment: as above required, I installed elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api and elasticsearch-transport gems on local machine

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

```
uninitialized constant Elasticsearch::Model (NameError)
```

because you haven't included the proper class. Try adding:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
```

At the top of your code.